# Shifting left in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, bit-shift

In my method one, I have the number that I want to shift by stored inside $a0 (e.g. 5 bits), and I want to shift $t9 by 5 bits, but I'm running into a bit of trouble. Does anyone know why?

```
MethodOne:

sw $a0, ($t8)
sll $t9, $t9, $t8
```

Comment: What is your touble? How was the values of $t9 before sll and after sll?

Comment: What purpose is the `sw $a0, ($t8)` supposed to fill? Why not just use `sllv $t9,$t9,$a0` ?

Comment: If you want to shift by a variable amount use the `SLLV` instruction. If you don't have `SLLV`, write a loop to shift left n times, one bit at a time

Comment: without the expected result, this is off-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To shift left by a variable amount, use `sllv`:

```
sllv $t9, $t9, $a0
```

`sll` only takes an immediate shift amount. There is no need for `sw` or `$t8`.